# getting href-data using selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I have the following html extract

0.94

I am trying to read the href value ie 0.94.I tried the following :

answer = browser.find_element_by_class_name("res")
print answer
output = answer.get_attribute('data-href')
print output

The Result is as follows:

None

I tried various other methods, using find_element_by_xpath etc,but not able to get the desired value ie. 0.94 (as in this example).
How can I get this value in the shortest way? Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML Extract:                                                                                           <a onclick="return insertInto('box','0.94');" title="Insert this answer into box" class="res" href="javascript:;">0.94</a>

Answer (score 0):

Use getText method if you want to to print 0.94